# Delegated vs federated authentication

Tags: authentication, oauth, authorization, oauth-2.0, openid

I am writing several web applications using Node.js. Within all these application I need authentication and authorization. What I do not want to do is to handle authentication and authorization in each single web application.

Hence I started to think about having a delegated and / or federated authentication mechanism, and have dealt with OpenID and OAuth(2) so far.

Nevertheless, I am not sure whether I am on the right track.

What I want is:

- Having a centralized authentication server (this is possible using both, OpenID and OAuth).
- It should not be possible for ANYBODY to authenticate (this is clearly pushing me from OpenID to OAuth, as I explicitly do *not* want to allow ANY OpenID provider, e.g.).
- I want to enable federation: The user should be able not only to authenticate against my centralized authentication server, but this server shall do federation with some pre-selected other authentication servers (think of integrating the server with an existing ActiveDirectory). I am not sure whether this is possible with OAuth, is it?
- I want my web applications to only trust tokens coming from *MY* centralized server (or, indirectly, from one of the trusted federated ones). Is this possible with OAuth2 Bearer Tokens?

Lots of questions ... I know that I could have all of this using SAML with WS-Trust and WS-Federation, but I would to opt for a more lightweight authentication strategy.

Any ideas, hints or suggestions on this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do all this. In fact you would be able to bridge your apps with ANY identity provider on ANY protocol, like AD or an LDAP directory. (That is exactly what we do in [our server](http://www.auth0.com)).

Since you are on node.js, I would strongly recommend you look at the excellent [passport](http://passportjs.org/) middleware as a starting point.